# Is it possible to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-k+1}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am solving a problem counting the number of subset $A$ of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$, such that there are no two adjacent numbers in A. Assuming $|A|=k$, I get $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$, so I am considering computing $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-k+1}{k}$$ to get the answer.

Comment: Please edit to include your effort.  A natural starting point might be to compute your sum for small $n$ and to try to detect a useful pattern.  (Hint:  the series is easily identified).

Comment: Simple experimentation suggests these are the Fibonacci nubmers $F(n+2)$ as in https://oeis.org/A000045 .

Comment: Welcome to MSE consider showing your attempts the problem and check out the code of conduct on how to ask

Answer (score 0):

The sums along the "one to the right, one diagonal right-up" diagonals of Pascal's triangle (see below for a visualisation of these diagonals using numbers, and using colors) yields the Fibonacci numbers.

> [image: Image of Pascal triangle with the mentioned diagonals indicated with numbers]
>
> [image: Image of Pascal triangle with the mentioned diagonals indicated with colors]

We can see this using, for instance, induction. Diagonals 1 and 2 (red and yellow) clearly add to $1$ and $1$, respectively. Now look at two subsequent diagonals. Note that most of their entries lie side-by-side, adding up to an element from the next diagonal. This aligns perfectly with the defining difference equation of the Fibonacci sequence.

The exceptions are

- possibly a single square at the top-right of the former diagonal
- always a single square at the bottom-left of the latter diagonal

In either case, the exception square must contain a 1, and right below each of those exceptions is a square from the next diagonal, and that square contains a 1. (If you are one of those people who like to extend Pascal's triangle infinitely to the right and to the left with $0$s in all rows, then there aren't even any exceptions.)

Thus the sum along one diagonal is equal to the sum along both the two preceeding diagonals together, and we get the Fibonacci sequence as a result.

Comment: I think I goofed when I numbered the diagonals, and my diagonal number $2$ corresponds to $n = 0$ in the sum in the problem, and so on. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n}$$:number of ways to form a “n” digit number with only 1 and 2 such that no  two “digit 2” are consecutive
$$$$now number of ways to choose where to place 2 among  n spots and how many to place will be equal to what you are trying to find.
$$$$also we can break this into 2 cases
i) when first digit is 2:
now second digit will also be equal to 1. so,$$a_{n-2}$$
ii)when first digit is 1
so, $$a_{n-1}$$
therefore, $$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
also by evaluating the original expression at n=1 and n=2:
$$a_{1}=2$$
$$a_{2}=3$$
so you will basically get the Fibonacci series which is
$$2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,……$$